# Swift 2 query printing with Optional wording

Tags: ios

```
    let username = self.user?.getProperty("username") as? String
    self.navigationItem.title = "@\(username)"
```

What I want to happen there is for it to print on the screen that users username with an @ in front of it like @user2

What it is printing instead is @Optional("user2")

How do I make this stop that? Ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String Interpolation prints also literal `Optional(...)` if the value is an optional.

To avoid that use either optional binding

```
if let username = self.user?.getProperty("username") as? String {
   self.navigationItem.title = "@\(username)"
}
```

Or the ternary conditional operator

```
let username = self.user?.getProperty("username") as? String
self.navigationItem.title = username != nil  ? "@\(username!)" : ""
```

In the first example the title won't be updated if username is `nil`, in the second it's updated with an empty string.

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. Still learning my way through this. Ill check yours once the timer allows it.